# Use trace.axd for a single page

Tags: asp.net, trace

Is there a way to use the trace.axd handler for tracing a single page on my site? I'm trying to monitor something in production, so I don't want tracing output to the page, but I also want to limit the output to a specific page.

Edit: I also would prefer to have a running record of the requests aggregated, like trace.axd does.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [page-level tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx) (it will not use trace.axd, the output will still be in the page)
With [Trace.IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.tracecontext.isenabled.aspx) you can also enable page-level tracing programmatically, so you can show the trace information in the page only if certain conditions are met (for instance you could have a parameter in querystring where you can say `yourpage.aspx?displayTraceInfo=true`). This way you would not risk having all your users see the trace information in the page.

Comment: Hm, that's a thought. Question edited for another benefit of trace.axd.